# DBCC FREEPROCCACHE and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS alike for specific scope

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I would like to check options to improve my queries.

sometimes, i want to do the tests on a production server so i can't use DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
and DBCC DROPCLEANBUFFERS to clear the entire server cache.

could you please share with me the way to do a kind of "cache clean" only for my connection/scope?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`DBCC FREEPROCCACHE (plan_handle | sql_handle | pool_name)`

By passing the plan_handle or the other options we will be able to cleare the cache of a particular sp or a query.

Answer (score 2):

Buffers are not held in a user specific table, or stored per user - there is no way for SQL Server to selectively clear it, since it does not know what items are being held for which queries; doing so would produce unneeded overhead in almost every case (except what you are trying to do now. Sorry.) Despite this, there are options.

There are suggestions, however, to ameliorate the issue, even if the problem can't be avoided:

You can use with(RECOMPILE) to force the query to find a new plan, but that will not clear the cache.

You can run each query twice, to see how slowly/quickly it runs once the data is buffered.

You can repeatedly alternate the two methods, to see if they get faster, and what the speed difference converges towards.

You can run them a day or two apart, or after a server reset. (This is if the production server gets reset occasionally anyways.)

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/davidlean/archive/2010/10/24/quot-how-to-quot-performance-tuning-high-frequency-queries-test-harness.aspx) has additional ideas for testing in such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

If downtime is OK you can take the database offline and take it online immediately afterwards.